# How can I get rid of the Error "Invalid appsettings.json file?

Tags: c#, json, graph

If I start my program, I'll get an error like: "**Invalid appsettings.json file**"

I need this file to access the Graph API.

If I wrote my local directory of this file, it works.

The code is below:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
.Build();


appsettings.json:
{
  "tenantId": "",
  "applicationId": "",
  "applicationSecret": "",
  "redirectUri": "https://localhost" 
}
```

Comment: Probably fixing whatever is broken in that file. Could you show it adding it to your question?

Comment: added the appsettings json

Comment: Could be that the JSON is not a valid format such as a character not being properly escaped. I'm not saying you should post your original credentials out here, but check somewhere if the json is actually valid.

Comment: As I said "If I wrote my local directory of this file, it works." 
The json is valid )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran the output of the CurrentDirectory and it was a wrong folder.
Then I wrote a little Replace Code that replaced the wrong folder with the right one.